# Processing XML using void elements as delimiters

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Here's the situation: I have some XML files that represent long-form document transcripts, in which page breaks are notated with a void element: <pb />.

What i want to do is build some kind of data struct (an array is fine) where each element represents the valid XML of each "page", as delimited by pb void elements (aka self-closing aka singleton).

The catch is, the pb elements can (and do) appear at any arbitrary nesting level, within any arbitrary parent nodes.

My thinking is to use XPath to identify each pb element, and then somehow close all the element's parent tags -- ending the page -- and re-open them to start the next page. I'm using [PHP DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Here's an example of what the XML looks like:

```
<text id="foobar">
 <div type="zing" n="zee">
   <pb n=1 />
   <p>some text</p>
   <p>more text</p>
   <fw><pb n=2 />page 2</fw>
   <p>blah blah</p>
   <p>blah blah blah blah <fw><pb n=3 /></fw> blah</p>
 </div>
</text>
```

And here's what I would want to transform that into:

```
<text id="foobar">
 <div type="zing" n="zee">
   <p>some text</p>
   <p>more text</p>
   <fw></fw>
 </div>
</text>
<text id="foobar">
 <div type="zing" n="zee">
   <fw>page 2</fw>
   <p>blah blah</p>
   <p>blah blah blah blah <fw></fw>
  </div>
</text>
<text id="foobar">
 <div type="zing" n="zee">
   <fw></fw> blah</p>
 </div>
</text>
```

Anyone think of a clever or elegant way to do this?

What i have now is a recursive loop inside another loop with multiple xpath queries per each iteration and it's fuuuugly.

Comment: If the id attribute is of the xsd:ID type, your plan won't work, of course.  You should be looking to convert the <pb/>s into containers.  In general, you will need a XML parser that lets you track the open element stack, which at each <pb> you "zip" up, plunk a </pb>, open a new <pb>, and "unzip" again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with so far. Like I said, fuuuugly.

```
// Given an XML transcript, return an array of pages indexed by <pb> element definitions.
function transcript_to_pages($transcript) {
  $dom = new DOMDocument();

  // 1. Compile the list of pagebreak DOM nodes we're looking for
  // 2. Build a string of all their anscestors
  // 3. chunk the transcript by pagebreaks
  // 4. prepend the ancestor strings to each chunk.
  // 5. build an array of the munged chunks
  $dom->loadHtml($transcript);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $pbnodes = $xpath->query('//pb');

  $close_string = $open_string = '';
  $i = 0;
  $total = $pbnodes->length;
  foreach ($pbnodes as $pbnode) {
    $page = '';
    $string = $dom->saveXML($pbnode);
    list($page, $transcript) = split($string, $transcript, 2);
    // The first <pb> element should have appeared as the first element of the
    // transcript. This would produce a leading blank page, which we'll skip. 
    if ($i++ == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    if (!empty($open_string)) {
      $page = $open_string . $page;
    }
    $parent = $pbnode->parentNode;
    $close_string = $open_string = '';
    while (!empty($parent)) {
      $close_string .= "</$parent->tagName>";
      $open_tag = "<$parent->tagName";
      if (!empty($parent->attributes)) {
        foreach ($parent->attributes as $key => $value) {
          $val = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $value->value);
          $open_tag .= " $key=\"" . $val . '"';
        }
      }
      $open_tag .= '>';
      $open_string = $open_tag . $open_string;
      if ($parent->tagName == 'text' || empty($parent->parentNode)) {
        break;
      }
      $parent = $parent->parentNode;
    }
    $page .= $close_string;
    $pages[$string] = $page;
  }
  return $pages;
}
```